# access nested json data angular in array

Tags: ajax, angularjs, jsonp

I have gone through a few posts and I am still having trouble accessing nested object data. I am using a factory to fetch weather info using jsonp:

```
this.testApi = function(coords) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp(API_ROOTS + '?key=khjsgf7bhv3y3hy776763&q=' + coords.latitude + ',' + coords.longitude + '&cc=yes&includeLocation=yes&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .then(function(response) {
          deferred.resolve(response.data);
          console.log(response.data.data);

        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

this returns a response that looks like this:

```
Object {current_condition: Array[1], nearest_area: Array[1], request: Array[1], weather: Array[5]}
```

now inside, lets say, current_condition, it looks like this:

```
0: Object
FeelsLikeC: "17"
FeelsLikeF: "63"
cloudcover: "0"
humidity: "23"
observation_time: "09:51 AM"
precipMM: "0.0"
pressure: "1028"
temp_C: "17"
temp_F: "63"
visibility: "10"
weatherCode: "113"
weatherDesc: Array[1]
weatherIconUrl: Array[1]
winddir16Point: "WSW"
winddirDegree: "250"
windspeedKmph: "7"
windspeedMiles: "4"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

the only problem is when I try access it in my html I get no out put:

{{place.current_condition.FeelsLikeC}}

does not seem to output anything...

Comment: {{places[0].current_condition.FeelsLikeC}} If places is a list

Comment: hey sorry, yes place is an object. Mistyped. here is the full json output that I am getting: [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/oyNboaZm0BtamnjuDypx?p=catalogue[/link] if, in my factory i output `deferred.resolve(response.data.data);` I get the json output in the plunkr

Comment: {{place.current_condition[0].FeelsLikeC}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **places** is javascript object, then you can use

```
places.current_condition[0].FeelsLikeC
```

If **places** is array, you can use something like

```
places[0].current_condition[0].FeelsLikeC
```

as **current_condition** is an array.